# API throwing error when doing a simple mutation apollo-graphql

Tags: react-native, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I'm a bit new within graphql and I don't know if I'm doing a syntax error when calling the mutation on the client, but It goes alright when I do the mutation on the graphical so I guess it's a problem with the client
graphiql:

```
mutation createUser {
  createUser (user:
  {
    name: "Apollo"
    email: "mail@mail.com"
    phoneNumber: "55219938385893"
    birthday: 1993
  }
  ){
    id
  }
}
```

createUser.ts

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag'

export const createUser = gql`
  mutation createUser(
    $email: String
    $name: string
    $birthday: String
    $phoneNumber: String
  ) {
    createUser(
      name: $name
      email: $email
      birthday: $birthday
      phoneNumber: $phoneNumber
    ) {
      id
    }
  }
`
```

signUpFormContainer.tsx

```
<Mutation mutation={createUser}>
        {(createUser, { data, error, loading }) => (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <SignUpForm
             loading={loading}
              onSubmit={(name, birthday, email, phoneNumber) => {
                console.log(name, birthday, email, phoneNumber)
                createUser({
                  variables: {
                    phoneNumber,
                    email,
                    birthday,
                    name
                  }
                })
                console.log(data, error)
              }}
            />
            {/* {!loading && !error && console.log(data)} */}
          </View>
        )}
      </Mutation>
```

Anyone got a hint where the error might be? thanks

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: can you post the mutation code.